# How to execute where query with parameter type array of string in entity frame work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an action method in asp.net core with parameter type array of string that contains multi category names

```
   public IActionResult Index(string[] categories,)
   {
       context.category.where(s=> s.name == string[] categories)
   }
```

I want to execute where query in the category context that category name must contain all of the values in this array. Without use of `for` or `foreach` loop

like this: `context.category.where(s=> s.name == string[] categories)`

Comment: I Found Answer for this

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
context.Category
  .Where(contextCategory => categories.All(c => contextCategory.Contains(c))
  .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Of `Any` is the Best way For Filter it by Category Name:

```
Context.Category.AsEnumerable().Where(c => categories.Any(s => c.LatinName == s)).ToList();
```

Comment: "I want to execute where query in the category context that category name must contain all of the values in this array"... Be careful, `Any` will filter for at least one not all values...

Comment: `Any` can check and compare if categories items exist in context category then filter it

Comment: `Context.Category.AsEnumerable()` will pull the whole category table into memory. What's the reason why you do this?

Comment: @S.nazari Yes, but `Any` means at least one not all the values, I have referenced your question...